# Can we call an another method when observe something

Tags: java, observable

I want to observe a queue limit.when it exceed the limit,I want to create another queue by calling a method

I tried to call the newqueue(create a new queue) method inside the overridden observer update method.

```
public void update(Observable o,Object arg){
    Bank bank = new Bank();
    if(arg == "went_over"){
        System.out.println("went over the limit");
        bank.newqueue();    //didn't work
}
```

where should I call that newqueue method?

Comment: The observer pattern might be what you are looking for. (https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern)

Comment: In what sense dit it "not work"? Is `update` being called (i.e., do you see the print output)?

Comment: Also, it seems like you're using `java.util.Observable` — that class has several design flaws and is deprecated in Java 9.

Comment: Yes ,I got the print output

Comment: @UdithShalinda Then again, in what sense did it "not work"?

Comment: @OhleC I tried to print the elements of both queues and only first queue was printed

Comment: @UdithShalinda please show us how and where you do that

Comment: @OhleC https://github.com/udith-shalinda/BankSystem

Comment: @UdithShalinda on that repo, the `Bank` class doesn't even have a `newqueue` method.

Comment: @UdithShalinda Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others, which shows how you handle the queue and want to "create" a new queue.

Answer (score 1):

Going from the github link you posted (which has different code, but nevertheless) the problem is that in the `update` method, you call `addtoque2` (which I think is what you refer to as `newqueue`, here) on a newly created instance of `Bank`. So the instance you create with

```
Bank bank = new Bank();
```

as a **local variable** in the `update()` method is the only one that gets this method called. I *presume* you actually wanted to act on the instance you created in `main`. If that is so, you'll have to somehow make a reference to it available in `update`. There's several ways to do that, including:

- Make the `Bank` a field in `FrontOfficer`, which is your `Observable` in this case, and access it through that.
- Delegate the creation of queues to `FrontOfficer` altogether
- If there will only ever be one bank, you could use the singleton pattern

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more context? A few more code snippets might give us the key.

Anyways, you are comparing `arg` to a `String`. If the Object received is a String, cool. If it isn't, it'll probably not work as intended. I'd say `if(arg.getName() == "went_over")` would be the way, supposing all Objects you pass have such a method?

Comment: if(rear<queueSize-1){
   customerque.add(customer);
   rear++;
  }else{     /*exceeding the queueSize*/
   setChanged();
   notifyObservers("went_over");
  }